# Running Costume Quest in Windowed Mode

Tags: costume-quest

I play a lot of "casual games" (think Diner Dash), and they all feature a way in their in-game options to run the game in windowed mode.

I bought Costume Quest yesterday for PC from Steam, and wanted to run it in windowed mode, however, unlike other games I play, I cannot find a way to tell the game to run in windowed mode.

Is there just a setting I am missing? Or is it something Steam doesn't allow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to run Costume Quest in windowed mode by setting launch parameters.

> To do that in Steam, open your Steam library, right-click on Costume
>   Quest, select Properties, and press the **Set Launch Options…** button.
>   Enter **–window** and click OK. The game will now launch and stay in
>   windowed mode until you remove this from your launch options.